# Async method with parameters called from Multiple tasks causes collision

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to asynchronous programming and am trying to upload say 2 files to a rest api in parallel. The upload process for each file consists of 3 rest calls
1. Initial put: To create the file
2. Append data using Patch
3. Save/flush the data in the file to commit it.

All this works sequentially but when I try to do it asynchronously, I get random failures because the parameters to the async method gets overwritten by the other task.

I have been following the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ and trying to follow a similar strategy

```
        private async Task<string> UploadFiles(string year, string month, string filename, string accesstoken, string path)
        {
            //Initial Put : corresponding to point 1 above in the summary
            var method = new HttpMethod("PUT");
            url = String.Format("https://someurl/part1/{0}/{1}/{2}?resource=file&recursive=True", year, month, localfilename);


            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url)
            {
                Content = null
            };

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);


            var initput = await client.SendAsync(request);

            //Append Data :corresponding to point 2 above in the summary
            url = String.Format("https://someurl/part1/{0}/{1}/{2}?action=append&position=0", year, month, localfilename);

            ****Here some code for file details which isn't necessary for this question***

            method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

            request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url)
            {
                Content = content
            };



            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            long? position = request.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

            //Flush Data:corresponding to point 3 above in the summary

            url = String.Format("someurl/part1/{0}/{1}/{2}?action=flush&position={3}", year, month, localfilename, position.ToString());

            request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url)
            {
                Content = null
            };

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);


            response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            return filename;

        }
```

And in the caller, I call it using multiple tasks, so that they start concurrently and then await

```
            Task<string> uploadCounterpartFileTask = UploadFiles(year, month, filename_counterparts, accesstoken, path);
            Task<string> uploadProductCategoryFileTask = UploadFiles(year, month, filename_productcategories, accesstoken, path);

            var allTasks = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> { uploadCounterpartFileTask, uploadProductCategoryFileTask };


            while (allTasks.Any())
            {
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task finished = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAny(allTasks);
                if (finished == uploadCounterpartFileTask)
                {
                    allTasks.Remove(uploadCounterpartFileTask);
                    var counterpartFile = await uploadCounterpartFileTask;
                }
                else if (finished == uploadProductCategoryFileTask)
                {
                    allTasks.Remove(uploadProductCategoryFileTask);
                    var productCategoriesFile = await uploadProductCategoryFileTask;
                }
            }
```

I expect this (though not in any particular order but ordered within the particular file or ordered within the task).

So, if I check Fiddler, I expect:

```
/part1/2019/02/Counterparts.avro?resource=file&recursive=True
/part1/2019/02/ProductCategories.avro?resource=file&recursive=True
/part1/2019/02/ProductCategories.avro?action=append&position=0
/part1/2019/02/Counterparts.avro?action=append&position=0
/part1/2019/02/ProductCategories.avro?action=flush&position=1664
/part1/2019/02/Counterparts.avro?action=flush&position=30907958
```

But I get:

```
/part1/2019/02/Counterparts.avro?resource=file&recursive=True
/part1/2019/02/ProductCategories.avro?resource=file&recursive=True
/part1/2019/02/Counterparts.avro?action=append&position=0
/part1/2019/02/Counterparts.avro?action=append&position=0
/part1/2019/02/ProductCategories.avro?action=flush&position=1664
/part1/2019/02/Counterparts.avro?action=flush&position=30907958
```

So, if you see for the "action=append", I get 2 calls for Counterparts but not for ProductCategories and therefore the flush action on ProductCategories fails because no append has happened on it first.

Basically what is happening is the parameter- filename in my async function is getting overwritten within tasks.

How can I ensure that the 2 files operate on these set of 3 REST calls in parallel, without overwriting the variables in the other task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of the url variable is not thread safe. I see that it is defined outside of your method, but then you use it and change it throughout the method.

When you have two asynchronous runs, using and changing the same variable you get race conditions.

Comment: Super thanks. That worked. I checked it by running it a few times and it works. So, I basically defined the url within the async function . It was defined outside as you point out because I have been testing many things. A;ll this while, I was thinking it was something to do with the filename variable (which makes the url), whereas it was the url variable itself that was the problem. Thanks a bunch !